# Any positive power of bump function is still a bump function?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\chi(x) \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n) $ and $\chi \geq 0 $. That is $\chi$ is non-negative on its compact support set and all its derivatives are bounded. If $0< p< \infty$, is the function $\chi^p(x):= \big[\chi(x) \big]^p \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Well, I know that at least for even $p$ the answer is yes. But for general values of $p$ I having trouble proving the boundedness of $\nabla^m (\chi^p)$.

Or if we consider the special example $\chi(x) = \exp^{-\frac{1}{1-|x|^2}}$ for $|x|< 1$ and $\chi(x) =0$ otherwise, then the statement is also true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true in general.  For instance, let $\chi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ be a nonnegative function such that $\chi(x)=x^2$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$.  Then $\chi^p(x)=|x|^{2p}$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$.  This function is not smooth at $0$ unless $p$ is an integer.

Comment: Your example is not $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: I'm not saying $\chi(x)=x^2$ for all $x$, only on $[-1,1]$.  Then you extend that to some smooth function with compact support on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I understand now. So basically you multiply $x^2 $ by another cutoff function that is $1$ on $[-1,1]$. Thank you for the answer.